# Can we have different folder structure for mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

My project contains two different sections.

1. Quote and
2. ProductSale

I have created A folder called Areas in Web project and Created two subfolders Quote and ProductSale.

Each subfolders has the Model, view and controller in it.

When i tried to create the view, the TextboxFor<> option(intellisense) is not coming but Textbox option is showing in razor view.

Do i need to include anything else or do we need to change some mapping/routing?

Please help me with this issue?

Note: This is a asp.net mvc3 project

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the webPages section from the standard `Views\Web.config` to your new Views folders.
[This section](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html/) configures the WebPages framework to use MVC's view base type & helpers.

In the future, you should use MVC's built-in Add Area menu item, which will do this for you.